# Cannot See ODataController Derived Action URLs in Swagger UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am currently trying to use Swagger UI to interact with my OData enabled Web API.

Versions for the bits and bobs are as follows:

**.Net 4.5.2**,
Web API 2.2,
NuGet package Microsoft.AspNet.OData 6.0.0 for OData 4.0 endpoints,
Swashbuckle 5.3.2,
Swashbuckle.Core 5.3.2,
Swashbuckle.OData 3.0.0.

My application has a SwaggerConfig.cs and a WebApiConfig.cs as expected. And I have followed many of the instructions in [this article](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint), [this article](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v3/creating-an-odata-endpoint) and a few others on the web.

When I launch my API through Visual Studio, I initially get a new browser tab with the local host URL. If I append the word "/swagger" (no quotes) at the end of that URL, I get a nice Swagger UI in the same tab. This tab shows the name of of my API but not much else. I don't see any of the individual URL interfaces for the Actions exposed by my ODataController derived Controller. Moreover, underneath the displayed name of the URL, all I have is [ base url: , api version: v1 ] where "v1" is coming in from SwaggerConfig.cs (same with the API name).

I know I can talk to the API from Swagger UI because I can arrive at the "Get" action of the Controller by modifying the displayed URL appropriately. The actions created were the standard Get, Put, Post, Patch, Delete ones. But I cannot see any of these in the Swagger UI.

This is because I am new to this and obviously have missed out or miscoded stuff to link everything correctly. I have made very little change to SwaggerConfig.cs and left most of the things as they were when it was created. The significant change I have made was adding this line:

c.CustomProvider(defaultProvider => new ODataSwaggerProvider(defaultProvider, c, GlobalConfiguration.Configuration));

Based on this info, if anyone can guide me in the direction of what pieces could be missing or developed incorrectly, I would greatly appreciate it. If you had any further questions for me, I would be happy to respond in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that because I had been recreating the application, Entity Framework was no longer creating the database for me since it was trying to use a name it had already recently used (a known EF bug). So I refractored the name of the database to something else. After this, things were plain sailing.

This negates my comment: "I know I can talk to the API from Swagger UI because I can arrive at the "Get" action of the Controller by modifying the displayed URL appropriately. The actions created were the standard Get, Put, Post, Patch, Delete ones. But I cannot see any of these in the Swagger UI."

Clearly this was me not understanding the issue clearly. But by going through the steps again one by one, I was able to find the problem and come to the desired place :)

Comment: can you supply a link to this Known EF Bug?